# Class member set(value) get called recursively... why?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class as below

```
class Employee(var person: String = "Employee", var worksAt: String = "California", var mood: String = "Happy") {
   var name: String = "Name: "
        set(value){
            name = "Name: $value"
        }

    var allString: String
        private set

    init {
        this.allString = "$name works at $worksAt is $mood"
        this.person = "Person: " + person!!
        this.worksAt = "Work at: " + worksAt
        this.mood = "Mood :" + mood
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return this.name + "\n" + worksAt + "\n" + mood
    }
}
```

When I set the name

```
        val reaEmployee = Employee()
        reaEmployee.name = edt_main.text.toString()
```

The name get set recursively infinitely... i.e. get `Name: Name: .... $value`...  until out of memory. What have I set incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because inside the setter for `name` you are setting the `name` again, which calls the setter.

You should use [`field`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) to access the backing field rather than call the setter.

```
field = "Name: $value"
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I follow the example in https://antonioleiva.com/classes-kotlin/, and got into this. I'll inform Antonio about it. Thanks!